# Relational database redundancy and normalization

Tags: database, entity-relationship

lets say we have a relational schema as follows
mortgage (HomeOwerID, Agent, LoanAmount, InterestRate)

an Agent can appear in any number of mortgages. is there any redundancy here? if so how could it be normalized

Comment: What are your functional (and multivalued) dependencies?  What is the primary key or candidate keys for the table?

Answer (score 1):

Data Redundancy is classified on

1] What is considered appropriate in database

2] What is considered excessive or wasteful

In your case "Agent" is considered appropriate redundancy in database.

Suggesting you the following.

1] Create table named Agent having fields like Agent_Code,Agent_Name (Keep Agent_Code Primary key)

2] Create foreign key on Mortgage table having Agent_Code referring Primary key of Agent table

Above will give you appropriate redundancy with better performance while running query against database.

Answer (score 1):

No.  The term redundancy refers to a *fact* being stated, explicitly, more than once in the database.  Not to the same attribute value appearing more than once.